# After Effects Script works manually, but not on start up

Tags: javascript, scripting, after-effects

I have a script (.jsx) that runs correctly when I load the project and run it myself. However, when I run it on start up by putting it in the StartUp folder it gives me this error:

"Unable to execute script at line 1. After Effects error: Unable to call "item" because of parameter 1. The range has no values"

Here is my script:

```
var compToBeOutput = app.project.item(35);
var comp1 = app.project.item(1);
var numGames = 7;
var p = 3;

compToBeOutput.duration = (90*numGames)/30;

compToBeOutput.layers.add(comp1);


  for (i = 0; i<numGames-1; i++) {
    var newComp = comp1.duplicate();
    var newLayer = compToBeOutput.layers.add(newComp);
    newLayer.startTime = p;
    p = p + 3;
  }
```

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: I know nothing about scripting After Effects, but it sounds to me like `app.project` has no "items" yet, possibly because After Effects loads your startup script before opening your project.

Comment: You're right, I added a sleep time to it but while it's doing it's 10 second sleep the project doesn't.  I think the startup scripts load first, then the project itself

Answer (score 0):

That is because item here is undefined. app.project.item is only accessible when project is open. so you need to open project first in the script itself.

For example.

var myPath = new File("you file path here");

if(myPath.exists){
  app.open(myPath );

}

then paste your script underneath.